# Moving to Function/Hooks/redux model breaks scroll behavior

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am rewriting an app to convert the top-level class component to a function component, and use useEffect hooks and redux, and I am confounded by this problem.

[Old version (works)](https://stopthegop.netlify.app/)

[New version (has a problem](https://61a2dbcce007ea00072b079c--stopthegop.netlify.app/)

The problem: When the right div scrolls, I want this to cause the left one, a react-select component's menu list, to scroll so that the topic at the top of the right div is always visible in the left one.

Instead of this happening, the left one scrolls back to the top with the first mouse wheel tick scrolling the right div. Then it renders three more times. The command to cause it to scroll doesn't do anything. I can see that in the old, working version the left component is rendering several times too, but in none of these renders does it scroll to the top. I don't know why it doesn't do that in the old version and I don't know why it does do that in the new one. I'm hoping that this has a stock answer or that someone has an article to help me better understand what's going on in renders and how I can change it.

I don't think the answer lies in the following differences, but here is how the left-side component which itself contains the react-select component, is included in the top-level component in each version:

Old version:

```
                    <SearchBox
                      groupedTopics={groupedTopics}
                      topics={topics}
                      ui={ui}
                      vars={vars}
                      inputValue={inputValue}
                      stickyGroupHeadings={stickyGroupHeadings}
                      searchRef={this.searchRef}
                      filteringFunction={filteringFunction}
                      isMenuOpen={isSearchMenuOpen(vars.IS_WIDE_SCREEN, selectionMade, isInitialHashValid, hashValue, hasFocus, anyTopicsForHash)}
                      onFocus={this.handleSearchBoxFocus}
                      onBlur={this.handleSearchBoxBlur}
                      onClickGroupHeading={this.handleSearchBoxClickGroupHeading}
                      onInputChange={this.handleSearchBoxInputChange}
                      onSearchChange={this.handleSearchBoxSearchChange}
                      onMenuScroll={this.handleSearchBoxMenuScroll}
                    />
```

New version:

```
                  <SearchBox
                    groupedTopics={groupedFilteredTopics}
                    ui={ui}
                    vars={vars}
                    inputValue={inputValue}
                    menuListRef={menuListRef}
                    isMenuOpen={isSearchMenuOpen()}
                    searchFilter={searchFilter}
                    onClickGroupHeading={handleSearchBoxClickGroupHeading}
                    onFocus={handleSearchBoxFocus}
                    onBlur={handleSearchBoxBlur}
                    onInputChange={handleSearchBoxInputChange}
                    onScroll={handleSearchBoxScroll}
                    onSelectTopic={handleSearchBoxSelectTopic}
                  />
```

UPDATE: This is very interesting. In the old, working, version, SearchBox was a function component and the Main component was a class component. Then I tried converting the Main component from class to function and it broke. Converting the SearchBox component from a function component to a class component got it to work. I tried doing this in order to use the shouldComponentUpdate method which is not available to function components, but that wasn't necessary. I just converted it to a class component and it worked.

So it works when the top component is a function component or the subcomponent is a function component, but not when both of them are. I don't consider this problem solved. Function components should not have this problem. If anyone can explain to me why this is so, please let me know. I would like to stick with function components if possible. That seems to be the way React is going. Is this a React bug?

Comment: I think the issue is specific but the set up you have made is project-related rather than a specific function not working... It'd be necessary to review the entire app... Maybe try to isolate the issue to a specific function and then you will have answers for it

Comment: I got it to work by converting the subcomponent from function type to class type. @DavidSalomon If you have any ideas why that worked or what the underlying problem could be so I could stick with function components, let me know.